# flash car racing game help?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I want to develop a car racing game using flash and actionscript3.
Can anyone recommend special books, open source projects, or articles which can help me start?

Comment: What kind of car racing game? Top-down/first person? 2d/3d? What parts are you having trouble with? What have you done so far?

Comment: -1 for your attitude in the comment of www0z0k's answer and i'd give another -1 for the lack of detail in your question if i could

Answer (score 4):

[google might help](http://www.google.com/search?q=flash%20car%20racing%20game%20tutorial)
 
http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2007/05/15/create-a-flash-racing-game-tutorial/

Comment: Sir, If you read carefully my post, and read the results of the google search, you will find that I am asking about books not only articles. eventhough, the proposed article is based on actionscript2 not 3. So plz be professional when answering, not just to answer.

Comment: you can add 'as3' to my google request as well.  your question's got a lack of details and it's difficult to tell what's being asked; code samples for quick change and  upload to some game hosting most likely, but no matter for the reason you need it, you don't seem to care to google it yourself and i don't think anyone's going to find or create one for you